# What is the function of this device in the middle of the man-made lake?

Tags: liquid

Can anyone identify what the blue and orange floating item with paddles is in this picture of what appears to be a Chinese fish or turtle farm?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an aerator for the pond. They use them for oxygenating the water and for circulation. [Link to the Pentair model in picture](https://pentairaes.com/paddlewheel-aerators-for-aquaculture-waste-water.html)

Comment: And in a round pond they can  be placed to make the pond rotate sending all debris to the center ( bottom).